# An error occurred while sending the request while post some data from console to web API use PostAsJsonAsync

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I wanna post some data from console to web API on same windows server and there is my code:

```cs
foreach (var i in txt)
{
  string[] j = i.Split("|");
   try
   {
    SomeModel d = new SomeModel()
    {
      Id = Guid.NewGuid(),
      Name = j[0],
      PhoneNumber = j[1],
      Custid = j[2],
      ZipCode = j[3]
    };
 
       var client = new HttpClient();
       client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:5000/");
       client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
       client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
       client.DefaultRequestHeaders.AcceptCharset.Add(new StringWithQualityHeaderValue("utf-8"));
       string body = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(d);
       string signature = GetRSA(body, privatekey);
       client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("signature", signature);
       HttpResponseMessage resPost = await client.PostAsJsonAsync("api/SomeApi", d);
   }
   catch (Exception ex)
   {
       Console.WriteLine(ex.Message, ex.InnerException, ex.StackTrace)
   }
}
```

some exception was occurred as follow :

execption :

> An error occurred while sending the request

> System.IO.IOException: Unable to read data from the transport connection:
> A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time,
> or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond..
> ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (10060): A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond.
> --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
> at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.AwaitableSocketAsyncEventArgs.ThrowException(SocketError error, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
> at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.AwaitableSocketAsyncEventArgs.GetResult(Int16 token)
> at System.Net.Http.HttpConnection.FillAsync()
> at System.Net.Http.HttpConnection.ReadNextResponseHeaderLineAsync(Boolean foldedHeadersAllowed)
> at System.Net.Http.HttpConnection.SendAsyncCore(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)

> at System.Net.Http.HttpConnection.SendAsyncCore(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
> at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.
> SendWithNtConnectionAuthAsync(HttpConnection connection, HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean doRequestAuth, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
> at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.SendWithRetryAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean doRequestAuth, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
> at System.Net.Http.RedirectHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
> at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.FinishSendAsyncBuffered(Task`1 sendTask, HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationTokenSource cts, Boolean disposeCts)

how can I fix this exception from `HttpResponseMessage resPost = await client.PostAsJsonAsync("api/SomeApi", d);`

Comment: The error suggests that your API isn't running on port 5000 on the same computer as your console application.

Comment: I've try to hit the API with Postman on same computer but the API responses as expected.